# In search of a specific inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, functions, inequality

We assume $i_1,i_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ (without 0) and $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.
We are given the following quantity
$$|a_1^{i_1}\cdot a_2^{i_2} - b_1^{i_1}\cdot b_2^{i_2}|$$
I am in search of an inequality only using $|a_1-b_1|$ and $|a_2-b_2|$. I.e. I want to find an arbitrary function s.t.
$$|a_1^{i_1}\cdot a_2^{i_2} - b_1^{i_1}\cdot b_2^{i_2}| \leq f(|a_1-b_1|,|a_2-b_2|,i_1,i_2) $$

---

My approach was to use Cauchy to get
$$|a_1^{i_1}\cdot a_2^{i_2} - b_1^{i_1}\cdot b_2^{i_2}|\leq \sqrt{(a_1^{2\cdot i_1}+(-b_1)^{2 \cdot i_1})\cdot (a_2^{2 \cdot i_2} +b_2^{2 \cdot i_2})}$$
But now the problem is $2^{2i_1}|a_1^{2i_1}-b_1^{2i_1}| \geq |a_1-b_1|^{2i_1} $ so I am stuck with that.

Comment: Your function must depend on $i_1, i_2$. Consider $b_1=b_2=0, a_1=2, a_2=1$. Then you want to bound $$ 2^{i_1} \leq f(2,1).$$ the RHS is just a constant and the LHS is unbounded.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes you are right. I edited the question. This is also allowed.